# Does Barbarian reckless attack apply to only the first attack or all attacks that turn the Barbarian makes?

Tags: dnd-5e, barbarian

Does Barbarian reckless attack apply to only the first attack or all attacks that turn the Barbarian makes? I've recently gotten into a discussion and the group was saying its for the first attack only that turn the Barbarian makes. What about if he has multiple attacks? Would it apply if I wanted to reckless with those also?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I can see where the confusion may lie.

Reckless Attack states:

> When you make your first attack on your turn, you can decide to attack recklessly...

That could easily be construed as only applying to the first attack but that is only stating the condition with which you can decided to use Reckless Attack. You can only decide to use Reckless Attack when making your first attack of the turn but it **applies** to all attacks for that turn as stated by the following text:

> ... Doing so gives you advantage on melee weapon attack rolls using Strength **during this turn,** but attack rolls against you have advantage until your next turn.

Comment: Great answer. Instead of only saying the correct interpretation, you went the extra mile and pointed out where the confusion stems for. Very educative. **One thing to remember when reading 5e rules block:** *the whole block is one single rule. Don't nitpick, don't break down and read only the juicy parts on your own convenience.*

Answer (score 16):

#### All attacks for the turn are affected.

Looking at the PHB, the text for Reckless Attack says

> When you make your first attack on your turn, you can decide to attack recklessly. Doing so gives you advantage on melee weapon attack rolls using Strength during this turn, but attack rolls against you have advantage until
>   your next turn.

What this means is:

1. Let's say it is your turn. You are about to make your first attack during this turn.
2. Before rolling your first attack, you make the decision of whether or not to attack recklessly.
3. If you decided to attack recklessly, then you get advantage on *all* Strength-based melee weapon attack rolls for the turn.
4. If you decided not to attack recklessly, then you roll normally for these attacks instead.

Your original position was correct.

Comment: I would note that while all the attacks are affected, the first restriction means **you can only choose to activate it during your first attack.** - although I don't see any reason to choose to apply it later, except for forgetting or simply late decision.

Comment: @HellSaint one use case is if your first attack happens to roll higher than expected damage and finish off the main damage dealer on the enemy team and you are less concerned with your enemy's getting advantage but it's still too late to activate reckless attack so you miss out on the opportunity