# Is Reckless Attack active with Retaliation?

Tags: dnd-5e, attack, barbarian

For the Barbarian, is Reckless Attack still active if you retaliate (lv 14 Path of the Berserker) against someone when they hit you? On Reddit, it said for the Fighter's Evasive Footwork that,

"While most people see the game in rounds, that is not how things happen at all. If your character moves even 5ft, you're in movement until your next turn. Everyone's rounds happen at the same time, and just because you didn't use your full 30ft of movement that does not mean you stopped moving, just that you're moving more slowly. All that means just one thing: Evasive Footwork functions like the Shield spell, but without costing any action to cast."

I'm wondering if the same idea is true for Reckless Attack - is it still active until your next turn?

For quick reference, Reckless Attack states: "Doing so gives you advantage on melee weapon attack rolls using Strength during this turn, but attack rolls against you have advantage until your next turn."

Comment: Also, welcome to the stack! Please take our [tour] to learn more about how we operate and you can also visit the [help] for more info.

Comment: Very related and possible duplicate on [Does barbarian reckless attack apply to only the first attack or all attacks that turn the barbarian makes?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/124006/does-barbarian-reckless-attack-apply-to-only-the-first-attack-or-all-attacks-tha)

Comment: @NautArch Definitely related, but certainly not a duplicate. That question is about attacks taken on-turn, this one is about attacks taken off-turn.

Comment: @T.J.L. Fair enough! I wasn't sure since it was so clear that it was on-turn and this is off-turn, but let's keep this open.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### No, Reckless Attack is not active by the time you take your reaction

Combat is broken down into **rounds**, during which everyone takes a **turn** (Player's Handbook chapter 9). There follows, in the rules, a description of what you can do during your turn. Namely, an action, movement and possibly a bonus action.

So when something says it lasts for your turn or "during your turn", it lasts only for that moment until you have completed your action/movement/bonus action.

After that, it may still be the same round but it is no longer your turn.

Comment: while it's not expressly asked, I would like you to point out that it would be active during a retaliation that occurs on your turn (such as if you draw an attack of opportunity).

Answer (score -7):

Hate to bring this up again but I was looking for an answer for this as well, according to different sources it is allowed. The wording on the Reckless Attack on DND Beyond is this "When you make your first attack on your turn, you can decide to attack recklessly. Doing so gives you advantage on melee weapon attack rolls using Strength during this turn, but attack rolls against you have advantage until your next turn..

What people mainly point out is that you get advantage on weapon attack rolls during **this** turn, it doesn't say your turn but the round when you activate it. It is however required that you activate it on your turn by declaring it.

Sources: https://reddit.com/r/DnD/comments/8c4s8x/5e_barbarian_reckless_attack_ready_action, https://www.dndbeyond.com/forums/class-forums/barbarian/3210-reckless-attack

Comment: Just for future reference, if linking to a reddit thread, please use a direct link and not through a 3rd party. They're more likely to stop working leading to link rot, and may contain (intentionally or not) malware or other attacks.

Comment: Pretty sure it would have said **round** if it was supposed to be a round.

Comment: There are several features, like the basic *Dodge* action, which explicitly specify "until start of yout next turn". Reckless attack doesn't say that, because it doesn't do that.